# Simple flying text in css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, css

I have a shopping cart with a total at the bottom of the screen. I would like some way of simulating the itunes store method of notifying a purchase by the price flying down to the total. This is going to be on android and iphone/pod so something lightweight would be best. I use jquery on this site (not UI). Any Suggestions?

Basically I want to have text move from one position to another. So far I can work out how to find the to and from postions

```
  var p = $("#"+item).find("small");
  var position = p.position();
  alert("left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );
  var p = $(".total");
  var position = p.position();
  alert("left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );
```

Now to figure out how to move text from point A to point B.

Comment: Can you give some kind of reference picture for this event? What mark-up are you using? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: I will migrating to jquery mobile in he next big revision. At the moment it is all jqtouch.